# Params in roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When are the parameters loaded to Rosmaster when these parameters are included in the launch file?
It is assured that these parameters are loaded before the start of the nodes presents in the same launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254756/params-in-roslaunch/) by [agbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/29369/agbj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I can refer you to my answer to #q199608.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1